# sql count() function

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select pending =[dbo].[GetPendingPur_Qty]
(PD.pivId,PD.prodId, PD.ScaleId) from 
tbl_PIVD PD where pivId=10609
```

Hai the above query gives the result of present product quantity (i.e pending quantity). How to use count() function to count the pending of products which have, pending > 0.

Comment: use `group by having`

Comment: pls help me by rewriting the query...

Comment: `pending =[dbo].[GetPendingPur_Qty]` where is this came from?

Comment: check this link: http://www.dofactory.com/sql/having

Answer (score 0):

Move your function to WHERE clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tbl_PIVD PD
WHERE pivId = 10609 AND [dbo].[GetPendingPur_Qty](PD.pivId, PD.prodId, PD.ScaleId) > 0
```